# What is the appropriate Title for this Question?

Tags: discussion

There has been a lot of discussion around [this question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/8922/how-can-i-get-better-visibility-on-the-software-side-of-a-larger-hardware-softwa) as well as continuing discovery on the specifics of the situation.

I've tried to capture the essence of the underlying question in a new title that will also solicit wider feedback from the community. However, the OP is not happy with the new title.

What do you think the title should be?

Comment: As an aside, you and Tiago deserve kudos for working with the user to figure out exactly what he needed. :)

Answer (score 1):

### The Title Isn't the Issue

The title edits you made seem fine to me, but I also don't really have a problem with the changes or rollbacks made by the OP. The real problem with the question isn't the title, but the fact that the question is really an X/Y problem that probably belongs on [Workplace SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) instead.

As currently written, the question (and the title) are on-topic here. However, the *point of view* for the question is wrong since the OP is not a project manager and not responsible for the process in question. I address these issues in [my answer](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/8943/4271).

### Action Items

None. It's marginally on-topic, and has attracted some good answers. Refactoring the question title to address the underlying X/Y issue would probably make the question off-topic, and I don't think it should *currently* be closed or migrated.

Comment: I believe you've just said, succinctly, everything I was going to say in response!